# Why doesn't my IF work

Tags: batch-file

I have this problem with my IF query.

```
IF "!ProzentS_[%Temp_Counter2%]!"LSS"%MIN_THRESHOLD%" (
    set WARTUNG_[%Temp_Counter2%]=true
    ECHO XXXXXXXXXX %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_%Time% TEST !WARTUNG_[%Temp_Counter2%]! !BAT_[%Temp_Counter2%]!  >> %PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%
    )
```

Somehow it has a problem with the brackets

`"(" can not be processed syntactically at this point`

if I use "LSS" "EQU" or "GTR" it does not count them but if i put "==" there it works.

```
IF "!ProzentS_[%Temp_Counter2%]!"=="%MIN_THRESHOLD%" (
)
```

Can someone tell me why this happens.

Comment: put spaces around `LSS`. The parser can not differ between string and comparator without them.

Comment: you might also want to use `%Time: =0%` instead of just `%Time%` to replace the space with a zero (at ` 9:47`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need more space:

```
IF "!ProzentS_[%Temp_Counter2%]!" LSS "%MIN_THRESHOLD%" (
    set WARTUNG_[%Temp_Counter2%]=true
    ECHO XXXXXXXXXX %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_%Time% TEST !WARTUNG_[%Temp_Counter2%]! !BAT_[%Temp_Counter2%]!  >> %PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%
    )
```